# Why doesn't my box grow with its content when I have margin applied?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with the following: I have a box, and within it some content. I'd like both of them to grow the same pace and same ratio. However it still changes, so the line break is different in small state to bigger state.

If I remove the margin, it works, however margin/padding is important. 
I have the following code:

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.content{
  font-size: 6px;
  transition: font-size 2s ease;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.box:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.box:hover .content{
  font-size: 18px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain a little further. I dont see any diference from code to expected result

Comment: in the smaller state, the content is in 3 rows. when I hover and it grows, it changes to 2 rows

Comment: you want it to stay in 3 rows?

Comment: yes, with the exact place and size relative to the parrent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the number of lines as it is and make the transition look smoother. Then you could use `transform: scale(n)` to change the size of the element:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.content {
  font-size: 6px;
  transition: font-size 2s ease;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.box:hover,
box:hover .content {
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```